# Issue with HTTPS requests only to www subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I configured Apache to serve HTTPS requests and redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. But...

- http://example.com works
- http://www.example.com works
- https://example.com works
- https://www.example.com *does not work*

For https://www.example.com, the web browser just hangs and Apache shows nothing in the logs, no errors, no accesses. I am not even sure this is an Apache issue, I am a bit lost. Any hints?

My SSL certificate has CN `example.com` and my Apache config file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot ...
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        DocumentRoot ...    
        SSLEngine on
        ...    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If your SSL certificate doesn't have the `www.` domain in its chain, the vhost config won't be valid.

Comment: Strange though, my CA Gandi states that *"The www subdomain is added automatically by the CA, for example, example.com will secure both example.com and www.example.com"*

Comment: That will only happen if your certificate is a wildcard one. A wildcard certifciate will secure any subdomain you setup.

Comment: @alejdg [Gandi's doc says](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/ssl/csr): *If you have a single-address certificate to activate, if you create the CSR with the bare domain (e.g. example.com), the www subdomain is added automatically by the CA, for example, example.com will secure both example.com and www.example.com. The reverse is also true, if you create the CSR with the www subdomain, the bare domain will be also secure.*

Answer (score 0):

[Gandi's doc says](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/ssl/csr): *If you have a single-address certificate to activate, if you create the CSR with the bare domain (e.g. example.com), the www subdomain is added automatically by the CA, for example, example.com will secure both example.com and www.example.com. The reverse is also true, if you create the CSR with the www subdomain, the bare domain will be also secure.*

I just happen to have generated one with `www.example.com` as the Common Name but whatever the doc said with things being automatic I made sure to include alt names in the `.cnf` for OpenSSL that I used to generate the CSR with:

```
[ req ]
default_md = sha256
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
prompt = no
string_mask = utf8only
distinguished_name = host_distinguished_name
req_extensions = host_extensions

[ host_distinguished_name ]
commonName = www.example.com
stateOrProvinceName = Somewhere
countryName = US
emailAddress = root@example.com
organizationName = ACME

[ host_extensions ]
subjectAltName = @alt-names
basicConstraints = CA:false

[ alt-names ]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = example.com
```

Generated the private key and CSR on some Debian with:

```
$ subject=www.example.com
$ openssl genrsa -out ${subject}.key 2048
$ openssl req -config ${subject}.cnf -new -key ${subject}.key -out ${subject}.csr
```